# Open Source[in php] Tool Which can convert XML into UML Diagrams?

Tags: php, xml, uml, tool-uml

I had already searched on Github and SourceForge, but these keywords are so much **used** that i could not find any relevant result , specially on sourceForge. 
I want to know if there is any Open Source tool written in `php` for converting XML in UML diagrams. 
I dont want support for all UML diagrams , my main focus in **Class diagrams**.

Why i want this software?

I am developing a tool for extending UML diagrams, in order to inject security constrains at the time of designing system(UML creating). So, if i can get a open source written in `php` for converting `xml` into `php` than, it will save a lot of time. 
i am developing it in PHP so that it can be provided as a web service to all.

This question was never asked on SO(particularly for soucecode in `php`) , it will help others to find quick answer(whether any such tool exist or not), Converting XML to UML is a common topic.

Comment: The reason it's never been asked perhaps: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to convert your xml to php-classes with this : https://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP and than use php_uml (http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_UML/) from pear.

Never tryd one of this tools, but maybe you got it work.